# Adding classes to body using lifecycle hooks in vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use `beforeCreate` and `beforeDestroy` hooks in order to add classes to body. In some cases I need to add classes, in some not.

So I have such code in each component which requires this functionality:

```
  beforeCreate() {
    document.body.classList.add('has-background')
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    document.body.classList.remove('has-background')
  }
```

The problem is that if I navigate from one route to another, say from A component to B component, the `beforeCreate` of the B component executed first, and then `beforeDestroy` of the A component, which removes the `has-background` class.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Didn't get you. For example, if I navigate to a component which does not need has-background class, what should I do? Adding beforeCreate in every component with removing has-background (if needed) doesn't seem to be good solution.

Comment: have you tried using `beforeMount` instead of `beforeCreate` ? or add a $nextTick to `beforeCreate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```
beforeCreate() {
    this.$nextTick().then(() => document.body.classList.add('has-background'))
},
```

**Edit:**

I also suggest to use **created()** rather than **beforeCreated()**. But to achieve the best behavior, it is best to use **mounted()**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my project and I have applied something like this.

```
methods: {
  toggleBodyClass(addRemoveClass, className) {
    const el = document.body;

    if (addRemoveClass === 'addClass') {
      el.classList.add(className);
    } else {
      el.classList.remove(className);
    }
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'mb-0');
},
destroyed() {
  this.toggleBodyClass('removeClass', 'mb-0');
}
```